# How can I release a port that is still in use but not bound to a process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, tcp

I'm running a Python application that spawns multiple processes. It uses port 56008 to listen for client requests. Sometimes after closing it the port it used is still "in use". There are still some python processes that appear to be running but trying to kill them using `kill` doesn't seem to have any affect.

How can I free it up manually so I can restart my application?

More info:

Output of `ps -C python`

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
30118 pts/1    00:00:00 python
30131 pts/1    00:00:00 python
```

*There are about 30 lines in total of the format `[pid] pts/1  00:00:00 python`

Output of `netstat -tulp` (relevant line only):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:56008                 *:*                     LISTEN      -
```

Comment: There are no other lines that refer to port 56008? Are you 100% sure?

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick

```
sudo kill -9 `ps -C python | grep python | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: You could probably simplify that substantially to `killall -9 python`, unless things which called python because python was in their arguments are also stuck.  It's interesting, nonetheless, that netstat didn't report python as owning the socket.

Comment: @Falcon Very - I think it's related to them being sub-processes, and the fact that the parent process had died.

Comment: Maybe `netstat` wasn't run as root or the owner of the processes.

Comment: That seems more likely.

Comment: @Flup good point - the app was started using sudo and I wasn't logged in as root when running netstat.

Answer (score 0):

You may try and code properly how your application will exit (e.g. kill all children, close network sockets)